# Ruby modify a hash value in a Array using gsub

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, gsub

modify hashes in an array

```
{:sku=>"TP-PA211", :desc=>"description", :qty=>"", :qty2=>"1 en su sucursal", :price=>"30.02 D"}
```

I want to modify the hash qty2 with gsub the name of the array is details2

when I do this:

```
details2.collect {|item| item[:qty2].gsub(/[^\d]/, '') }
```

I get all the modified values.

Hash qty2=>"1 en su sucursal" needs to be changed to qty2=>"1" , so using .gsub(/[^\d]/, '') that can be done, but how do I change the value of the hash!? considering its an array of hashes.

tried this:

```
details2{|item| item[:qty2] = item[:qty2].gsub(/[^\d]/, '') }
```

Comment: It's not clear at all. What is it that you want to get? What is it that you're getting?

Comment: @Sergio the Hash qty2=>"1 en su sucursal"  needs to be changed to qty2=>1, so using .gsub(/[^\d]/, '')  that can be done, but how do I change the value of the hash!? considering its an array of hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to update items in-place, then you don't need `collect`. There's a simpler way. Try this:

```
details2.each {|item| item[:qty2].gsub!(/[^\d]/, '') }
```

That should replace your strings in-place.

Comment: awesome! so each updates the values in the array :O. thanks man.

Comment: `each` doesn't update anything. It simply iterates elements. `gsub!` does the updating.